# Issue with loading open cv library in app in android?

Tags: android, opencv

I am able to run the application using opencv in emulator with android sdk 4.4 (kitkat).
But getting issue while running in device jellybean 4.2.2.

I am following this http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/ link

Log:-

```
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
06-02 15:04:23.843: E/OpenCV::camera(12207): ||libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
06-02 15:04:23.844: E/linker(12207): soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:987): cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android17IConsumerListenerD2Ev" referenced by "libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so"...
06-02 15:04:23.846: E/linker(12207): soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:987): cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android6Camera17setPreviewTextureERKNS_2spINS_22IGraphicBufferProducerEEE" referenced by "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"...
06-02 15:04:25.216: A/libc(12207): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000003 (code=1), thread 12207 (encv.samples.fd)
```

If anyone have idea. please reply.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You're not implementing well your classes.

You're missing something on your headers, or maybe you're missing to add shared libraries to your NDK to make.